# What is the truth table for $p \Rightarrow q\land r$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If $p$ is true, and $q$ and $r$ are both false, is the statement true since the truth value of $p\land q$ is true? If $q$ does not have the same truth value of $r$, then is $q\land r$ false?

Comment: What does $p\land q$ have to do with the statement youre asking about?

Comment: Sorry, I meant q^r.

Comment: The truth table for the conditional $\Rightarrow$ logical operator requires that either $p$ be false or, if $p$ is true then $q\land r$ must be true as well.  If this does not hold then the condition itself is false.

Comment: If $q\land r$ is true then $p$ must be true or else the condition must be false.

Comment: Well, it is only trivially true in that case. Correct? Suppose p means 2+2=5. Then the statement is true, but trivially.

Comment: If $p$ was false and the conditional were true then the conditional is vacuously true, yes. This is possible. And it wouldnt matter what $q\land r$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{c|c}p&q&r&q\land r&p\to q\land r\\\hline T&T&T&T&T\\T&T&F&F&F\\T&F&T&F&F\\T&F&F&F&F\\F&T&T&T&T\\F&T&F&F&T\\F&F&T&F&T\\F&F&F&F&T\end{array}$$